# Bot crashed when trying to DM

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My Discord bot sometimes sends a message directly to the user, but if user turned off the messages from strangers it crashes.

Is there some If function that will check if you can send a message to this user? Or maybe some command, that will try to send a message to the user, but if it won't work, bot will ignore it and go on? I tried "try" but it doesn't work `DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user`

```
try{
   await client.users.cache.get(`${id}`).send('hello',{
      embed:embed1,
      });
   let messageEmbed1 = await client.users.cache.get(`${id}`).send({embeds: [embed1]})
   } catch (error) {
   console.error(error);
```

Comment: which of those two statements crashes the bot (I take it you mean the bot acutally crashes and you have to restart it)

Comment: Well, you can't send messages to that user. Simple as that. You got banned, he got banned, I don't know. But you just can't send the message, if you read the error.

Comment: uh, both I think. It didn't gave me the exact error. It just send the error that i can't send message to a user with closed dms

Answer (score 1):

`send` function is a async function, therefore you need to chain catch function instead of try catch scoping them.

```js
await client.users.cache.get(`${id}`).send('hello',{
      embed:embed1,
      });
   let messageEmbed1 = await client.users.cache.get(`${id}`).send({embeds: [embed1]}).catch(e=>{console.log(`Saved bot from crash, error:\n${e}`)});
```